# php composer: What is the purpose of autoload.php?

Tags: php, composer-php

**/vendor/autoload.php** calls **/composer/autoload_real.php**:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit011f2af2ab670c31c3caae2671068b02::getLoader();
```

I just wanted to learn about why this is necessary instead of just using autoload_real.php directly.

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with the seemingly random generated class `ComposerAutoloaderInit011f2af2ab670c31c3caae2671068b02`.  They may have been able to do it a different way, but this is a pretty simple solution.

Comment: Since classname is unique (per install probably), you wouldn't know how to get a hold of the autoloader object without hardcoding the name in your code each time you download/install. In this fashion, you can get a hold of it without knowing classname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer promises to deliver an interface to autoload every required library. This interface has been defined as "include `/vendor/autoload.php`, and you are done".

Composer internally first adds the internal classes to the PHP autoloader stack, starts up it's internal autoloading, then removes the internal classes autoloader from the stack, and returns control to the application.

Yes, there are randomly created class names which are supposed to only be known to the internal setup of the autoloader, but no external instance.

In the end: Why bother? If you think this process is not optimal, you could suggest optimizations or a pull request to the project.

Comment: Didn't say I thought it was implemented poorly, just wanted to understand it.